# In api gateway how I can publish documentation parts using CLI

Tags: command-line-interface, documentation, aws-api-gateway, publish

From aws API gateway console there is a button called "Publish Documentation" to add documentation parts to certain stage. 
I need to do the same but using CLI

Answer (score 0):

If you click that button you'll see you are creating a new Documentation Version. The CLI command for that is documented here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/apigateway/create-documentation-version.html